# Vienna: Command-W does not normally work

Tags: rss, macos

Hi I use [Vienna](https://github.com/ViennaRSS/vienna-rss) as my RSS reader.  I noticed that closing it without quitting it (that is, using Command-W rather than Command-Q), does not work most of the times.  If I quit Vienna and reopen it, Command-W works for a bit, then it stops working for reasons unknown.  How do I debug this?

I am on Ventura 13.0.1, but I had this problem in Monterey as well.

Comment: Is it only happening in Vienna or also in other applications? Do you have any utilities running which may capture key strokes? Did you reach out to the developer on this?

Comment: yes, no, and yes.

Comment: I like brevity, but this doesn't give us a lot to work on (and it's kind of hard to interpret the first "yes" :-)). What did the developer say? Did you create a new user account on your Mac to verify whether it occurs there as well? Could it be related to the keyboard (or to the way you press the keys when using this app)? Right now we can only guess.

Comment: Yes, it only happens to Vienna, no nothing captures my keystrokes (that I know of), yes I contacted the developer but nothing of any use came of it